Are Coefficients of Kinetic Friction Additive?
Question setup:
Say we have two blocks on a $30^{\circ}$ incline plane with masses $4\ kg (A)$ and $8\ kg (B)$.
The coefficient of kinetic friction between block $A$ and the plane is $0.25$, and that for block $B$ and the plane is $0.35$.
Imagine a scenario where block $A$ is placed further up the plane than block $B$, resulting in block $A$ accelerating faster down the ramp than block $B$ and causing an inelastic collision. Following that collision, the blocks move together down the ramp as a singular entity.
Question:
How would we calculate the new coefficient of kinetic friction for this compound block object?
Would we simply add the previous coefficients together? Take the mean of the individual values?
Or is this situation too complex to be handled using simple undergraduate mechanics?

Certainly not add, because we have upper and lower bounds of friction coefficients.

Are coefficient of friction additive?
No
Coefficient of friction depends on two surfaces in contact. If A was wood and B was ceramic sliding upon metal wedge, then coefficient of friction between wood and metal is different than that between ceramic and metal which are altogether different from what it would be for ceramic and wood. Most coefficients (adjustments, proportionality constants or correction factors,etc) are to be determined empirically.
Coming to present question, since there's inelastic collision, let's assume blocks stick to each other and don't separate until the end of experiment. The new joint block can be considered a different material altogether with a new coefficient of friction which can be determined as follows:
If you have an object moving at some velocity v and you let it slide along a surface until it stopped. You could then measure the time t it takes to stop to determine its coefficient of friction.
From the Force Equation, $F = ma$,
where a is the acceleration.
Since the object is starting at some velocity v and decelerating until v = 0, then the force of friction can be written as:
$$F_r = mv/t$$
$$F_r = f_r W = f_r m g$$
Combining the two equations for Fr, we get:$$ f_rmg = mv/t $$ or$$
f_r = v/(gt)$$

While I certainly agree with everything you stated, what if you're not provided any information about material whatsoever? Just numerical values for μ_k in a generic context with nothing else.

@trb7074 can you refer any specific question from some standard book or exam related to your query. ..

Sure:
Two blocks with masses 4.00 kg (block A) and 8.00 kg (block B) are connected by a string and slide down a 30.0° incline plane. The coefficient of kinetic friction between the 4.00 kg block and the plane is 0.250. The coefficient between the 8.00 kg block and the plane is 0.350.
a.) Calculate the acceleration of each block.
b.) Calculate the tension in the string.
c.) What happens if the positions of the blocks are reversed?

In part A, the acceleration is 2.21 m/s² for both blocks. In part B, the tension is 2.26 N. In part C, block A has an acceleration of 2.78 m/s², and block B has an acceleration of 1.93 m/s². This means that block A will end up sliding down the ramp and colliding with part B. My question is.. can we determine the acceleration of the compound block object following the collision with just this information provided?

Before the collision, you have two objects sliding down the plane. You calculate the forces on each separately.
After the collision, you have two objects sliding down the plane pushing on each other. Again you calculate for forces separately. Since they are in contact, you know they have the same velocity and acceleration.
